# GeoServer SLD styling: Ignore NaN values when generating pie chart

Tags: geoserver, sld, chart, geoserver-styling

I want to create a style in GeoServer to display a pie chart based on four attributes.

With the SLD code below I can create functional pie charts:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.0.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd"
  xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <NamedLayer>
    <Name></Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <Name>Pie charts</Name>
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Rule>
          <PolygonSymbolizer>
            <Stroke>
              <SvgParameter name="stroke">#000000</SvgParameter>
              <SvgParameter name="stroke-width">2</SvgParameter>
              <SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</SvgParameter>
              <SvgParameter name="stroke-linecap">square</SvgParameter>
            </Stroke>
          </PolygonSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
      </FeatureTypeStyle>
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Rule>
          <PointSymbolizer>
            <Geometry>
              <ogc:Function name="centroid">
                <ogc:PropertyName>geom</ogc:PropertyName>
              </ogc:Function>
           </Geometry>
           <Graphic>
              <ExternalGraphic>
                <OnlineResource
                  xlink:href="http://chart?cht=p&amp;chp=-1.5&amp;chf=bg,s,FFFFFF00&amp;chd=t:${attributA/100},${attributB/100},${attributC/100},${attributD/100}&amp;chs=50x25&amp;chco=ffdd00,008743,bfd630,f36f23" />
                <Format>application/chart</Format>
              </ExternalGraphic>
            </Graphic>
          </PointSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
      </FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

However, some entities have `NaN` values for one or more of the four attributes. As soon as an entity has a `NaN` value in at least one of the four attributes concerned the pie chart is not displayed and a small grey square is displayed instead (see screenshot).

[image]

On the screenshot you can see that some pie charts show less than 4 colors (attributes), this is because the entities concerned are equal to 0. In my case, I cannot replace `NaN` values with 0's in my table. So this is not a solution.

I would like to edit my SLD code in order to ignore the `NaN` values and that for each entity a pie chart is displayed based on the attributes that do not have a `NaN` value.

Is it possible to ignore `NaN` values when generating a pie chart?

Note: none of my entities has all four attributes equal to `NaN`.

Comment: I suspect that will require changes to the underlying graph drawing code or at least the GeoServer code that passes the values to that library